# Placing dynamically added buttons below each other

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

I'm building a calculator app and in it there's a ScrollView, used to show and switch the buttons for operators and units whenever the user switches between modes.

The problem is that I didn't want to create a XML layout for each mode, so I thought of adding those buttons programmatically (which now, for me, seems pretty hard to accomplish). Here's the code that's supposed to add them:

```
// For each text in texts (which represents the modes), a Button is created and, if its id (represented by the index of its respective text in the list) is greater than 0, it is positioned below the previous one.
fun ScrollView.add(context: Context, input: EditText, texts: List<String>) {
    removeAllViews()

    val container = ConstraintLayout(context).apply {
        layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
            topToTop = this@add.top
            startToStart = this@add.left
            endToEnd = this@add.right
        }
    }

    val buttons: MutableList<Button> = mutableListOf()

    texts.forEach { text ->
        val button = Button(context)

        val originalWidth = 60
        val width = originalWidth.toDimension(context, COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP)

        val originalHeight = 60
        val height = originalHeight.toDimension(context, COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP)

        with(button) {
            layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)

            id = texts.indexOf(text)
            val previous = try { buttons[id - 1] } catch (exception: Exception) { this }

            setWidth(width)
            setHeight(height)

            with(layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) {
                if (id == 0)
                    topToTop = this@add.top
                else if (id > 0) {
                    layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
                    (layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams).addRule(BELOW, previous.id)
                }
            }

            left = this@add.left
            right = this@add.right

            button.text = text
            isAllCaps = false

            textSize = 25f
            while (text().contains(System.getProperty("line.separator").toString())) textSize -= 5

            setOnClickListener { input.input((it as Button).text()) }
            setBackgroundResource(0)

            container.addView(this)
            buttons.add(this)

            val buttonAdded = "[Dynamic List] Button $id added as \"$text\""
            println(if (id == 0) "$buttonAdded." else "$buttonAdded. The button was positioned below \"${previous.text}\" (${previous.id}).")
        }
    }

    addView(container)
}
```

And here's the code I implemented using the method above:

```
// Each calculator mode is represented by an Int within the list.
val modes = listOf("calculator" to 1, "length" to 2, "temperature" to 3, "time" to 4)

fun mode(context: Context, button: Button, input: EditText, view: ScrollView) {
    var counter = 0

    val operators = listOf("+", "-", times.toString(), division.toString())
    val length = with(context) { listOf(getString(R.string.light_year), context.getString(R.string.kilometer), context.getString(R.string.hectometer), context.getString(R.string.decameter), context.getString(R.string.mile), context.getString(R.string.meter), context.getString(R.string.centimeter), context.getString(R.string.millimeter), context.getString(R.string.micrometer)) }
    val temperature = with(context) { listOf(getString(R.string.celsius), context.getString(R.string.fahrenheit), context.getString(R.string.kevin), context.getString(R.string.rankine), context.getString(R.string.reaumur)) }
    val time = with(context) { listOf(getString(R.string.year), context.getString(R.string.month), context.getString(R.string.day), context.getString(R.string.hour), context.getString(R.string.minute), context.getString(R.string.second), context.getString(R.string.millisecond)) }

    with(button) {
        setOnClickListener {
            if (counter < modes.size - 1) counter++ else counter = 0

            with(view) {
                val mode: Pair<String, Int>? = modes[counter]

                when (mode?.first) {
                    "calculator" -> add(context, input, operators)
                    "length" -> add(context, input, length)
                    "temperature" -> add(context, input, temperature)
                    "time" -> add(context, input, time)
                }

                text = with(context) {
                    with(resources) { getString(identify(context, mode?.first, "string")) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the problem is when I run it, the UI ends up looking like this, with all the buttons positioned at the same place:

[image: Calculator mode button positioning bug.]

Comment: If you want the buttons to be aligned vertically below one another, try using Linear Layout with orientation property "vertical", and simply add all the buttons to the dynamically created Linear Layout. And finally, add this Linear Layout to the ScrollView (as ScrollView can have only ONE direct child)

Comment: OMG, thank you, that worked! I can't believe the solution was that simple...

Comment: Glad, it worked.